# Why rollback not working in Access linked to sharepoint list

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, sharepoint, dao

I'm trying to insert data from Excel into an Access table that is linked to a Sharepoint list. I got this working, except for the fact that my transaction is not working. The new item always shows up in Sharepoint immediately after the `rs.Update` line. And the line `ws.Rollback` does nothing. Can anyone explain why this is happening and can this be made to work? The code:

```
Private Sub InsertData()
    
    
    Dim dbConnection As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim dbCommand As New ADODB.Command
    Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim sowItem As clsSowingEntry
    Dim crit As String
    Dim dKey As Variant
    Dim rsEvent As DAO.Recordset2
    
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    
    If datadict.Count = 0 Then
        Set datadict = Nothing
        MsgBox ("No valid sowing events were found.")
        End
    End If
    
    Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    Set db = ws.OpenDatabase(accessPath)
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("FormData")
    Set rsEvent = db.OpenRecordset("EventType")
            
    ws.BeginTrans
    For Each dKey In datadict.Keys
    
        Set sowItem = datadict(dKey)
        
        crit = "EventTypeId = 1 AND ProductionLineCode = '" & sowItem.ProductionLine & "' AND ProductCode = '" & sowItem.ProductCode & "' AND EventDate = " & sowItem.SowingDate
        
        rs.FindFirst crit
        If rs.NoMatch Then
            'Insert New Record
            rs.AddNew
            rs!SowingDate = sowItem.SowingDate
            rs!EventDate = sowItem.SowingDate
            rs!EmployeeName = sowItem.SowerName
            rs!EventTypeId = sowItem.EventTypeId
            rs!ProductionLineCode = sowItem.ProductionLine
            rs!ProductCode = sowItem.ProductCode
            rs!UnitCode = sowItem.UnitCode
            rs!GreenHouseCode = sowItem.GreenHouseCode
            rs!Quantity = sowItem.ActualCellCount
            rs!SeedBatchNumber = sowItem.SeedBatchNo
            rs.Update
        End If
        
    Next
    
    If MsgBox("Save changes?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        ws.CommitTrans
    Else
        ws.Rollback
    End If
    
    rs.Close
    db.Close
    ws.Close
    
    Set db = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set sowItem = Nothing
    Set datadict = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub
    
errHandler:
    ws.Rollback
    rs.Close
    db.Close
    ws.Close
    
    Set db = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set sowItem = Nothing
    Set datadict = Nothing
    
    Call Common.FatalError(Err.Description)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Afaik SharePoint lists are not transactional. You might have more luck if you swap the list to the old cache format (`WSS` instead of `ACEWSS` in the database `.Connect` property) as it does more caching in Access, but I'm not sure that'll help. The more obvious solution would be to prompt the user before making the change if the only reason you want transactions is to ask the user if changes should be saved.

Comment: @ErikA OK, thank you. The point of transaction here is that the user could verify the data to be inserted before committing, as the data structure the data is collected from is atrocious. But then again, I could print the sowItem objects for the user to verify before even stepping into the database operation. I also suspected your first sentence to be the case, but could not verify.

Comment: In a similar situation I've written data to a temporary, local table, with a form asking the user to check and confirm, and then uploaded it + deleted temp table afterwards. Resulted in some complex code and lacked the locking a normal transaction would have, but was okay for my purposes.